# Complex retrieval of a web document

Tags: java, post, cookies, redirect, https

I need to retrieve a document from a website, and parse it.
Problem is that:

1. The site uses both http and https protocol
2. You need to log in the site (I have a regular account)
3. From the login page, there are at least 2 redirect just to log in yourself

I managed an HTTPS connection and posted my login and pass, but I'm having troubles with cookie management and the redirect....

Comment: What are you using as your HTTP client?

Answer (score 1):

commons-httpclient would help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a library like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) would probably help.